# XSLT 2.0: Finding the starting and finishing index of a substring

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm taking an XML file of register and register bit data which includes a great raft of duplication and compressing it into a compressed notation. In order to do this, I need to detect when two or more register names indicate that they are, in fact, identical except for their names.

For example:

```
<register_block>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN0_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN1_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN2_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    .
    .
    .
    <register>
        <register_name>FN21_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
</register_block>
```

The identical nature of the names save for the incrementing digit indicates that the register is repeated, so I can safely strip the digit and express the 22 iterations of the register as a single compressed register. I used `tokenize()` and [0-9][0-9]+_  as the RegEx to strip the names so I could compare them and to construct the reformed name (minus the incrementing digit) and it worked, mostly.

Unfortunately some of the registers had the [0-9][0-9]+_ pattern occurring a second time, e.g. FN1_SONET_TX1_SQUARE, which threw a wrench into things since post-processing it would call TX1 and TX2 identical.

So, what I need is this:
an XSLT 2.0 way of detecting the FIRST occurrence of the [0-9][0-9]+_ pattern and its starting and ending index so I can determine if it's in the first half of the register name or the second and whether it's 2 characters long or three.

As a side note, I cannot be sure that the digit being incremented is within the first 3 or 4 characters of the name, but it will be closer to the start than the end, if it's there at all.

Comment: Hmmm. Fun; someone downvoted it for "not showing much research effort, being unclear, or not being useful" without bothering to comment on what lacked effort or was unclear. That seems lazy and unclear in itself. What irked you, Mystery Drive-by Downvoter?

Comment: I don't take response for the downvote, but I read your description and have no idea what you want to achieve. [mcve] may be a reason too, why you get downvoted. Show your current state of XSLT and expected output as XML in a minified version.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `replace`, not `tokenize` as follows:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="register_block">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="register" group-by="replace(register_name, '^(\p{L}+)[0-9]{1,2}', '$1')">
                <group name="{current-grouping-key()}">

                </group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Transforms

```
<register_block>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN0_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN1_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN2_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    .
    .
    .
    <register>
        <register_name>FN21_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT</register_name>
    </register>
    <register>
        <register_name>FN1_SONET_TX1_SQUARE</register_name>
    </register>
        <register>
        <register_name>FN1_SONET_TX2_SQUARE</register_name>
    </register>

</register_block>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<register_block>
   <group name="FN_FX_FIDO_FEED_HALT"/>
   <group name="FN_SONET_TX1_SQUARE"/>
   <group name="FN_SONET_TX2_SQUARE"/>
</register_block>
```